# Create signal-messenger tag and edit incorrectly tagged questions

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[My question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241141/word-completion-set-language-and-disable) was moved from SuperUser but now has an incorrect [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) tag (on SU it refers to the messaging app).
I see that e.g. [facebook-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger) or [whatsapp-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger) exist, but [signal-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-messenger) does not.

[Many questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bsignal%5D) tagged [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) are actually about the messenger app, this would justify the new tag.

I suggest creating [signal-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-messenger) and editing those questions (and maybe update the description for [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) to refer to [signal-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-messenger)).

I don't have enough rep to do the first step, so can anyone else add it.

Answer (score 3):

Created [signal-private-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-private-messenger) according to the app's official name and retagged the relevant questions.

Also, renamed [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) to [network-signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-signal) to disambiguate the tag. (Any idea for a better tag name is still open)

Comment: .... and you checked the questions ;-)